# Expression for the sum $S = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {2n \choose i} \cdot x^i \cdot (1 - x)^{2n - i}$

Tags: contest-math, binomial-coefficients

My question is if there a way to determine the formula or a simplifying form for the following expression:
$S = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {2n \choose i} \cdot x^i \cdot (1 - x)^{2n - i}$

where $0 < x < 1$.

What I noticed so far is that if we denote $S$ as a function of $x$, then we have that:

$S(x) + S(1 - x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{2n} {2n \choose i} \cdot x^i \cdot (1 - x)^{2n - i} = 1$

Unfortunately, I could not find any other relation about $S$.

Comment: ^No that's not right. The sum is only up to $n-1$

Comment: potentially helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204036/simplify-sum-i-0n-1-2n-choosei-cdot-xi?rq=1

Comment: Mathematica gives a closed form in terms of hypergeometric function $${{\left( 1-x \right)}^{2n}}{{\left( x-1 \right)}^{-2n}}-\frac{\left( 2n \right)!{{\left( 1-x \right)}^{n}}{{x}^{n}}{{}_{2}}{{F}_{1}}\left( 1,-n;n+1;\frac{x}{x-1} \right)}{{{\left( n! \right)}^{2}}}$$

Comment: Thank you all, this is useful!